# HMR not updating - Docker running vue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, vue.js, nginx

Running a docker-compose to host a client side , backend, database and NginX as proxy

Everything is working fine except the HMR which won't "hot reload"
I can only see changes on refresh

any ideas?

Code:

Docker compose to run

- Node (express)
- Vue
- MongoDB
- Redis

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  mongo-db:

services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./server/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - server
      - client

  client:
    build: ./client
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
```

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=1234
      - SESSION_SECRET=secret
    command: npm run dev

  mongo:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234

  nginx:
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
      - "8000:80"

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Vue Dockerfile (client)

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
ENV PORT 8000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Node Dockerfile (server)

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
    then npm install; \
    else npm install --only=production; \
    fi

COPY . ./
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

NginX default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://client:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://server:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

extra stuff -
No webpack.config.js file

Vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/assets/css/global.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000,
    },
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "$$ts-jest$$",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost", "es5", "es6"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "src/router/routes.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```